# Given sequence of coordinates, get order around origin by distance, without precise distance

Tags: coordinate-systems

Given a sequence of coordinates, what's the simplest way to get their order by stance around the origin, given that the absolute distance is of no consequence?

For example, given points `[ [0 5] [0 -1] [2 0] ]`, all these order expressions are correct:

`[ 3 1 2 ]`, `[ 5 1 2 ]`, `[-5 -1 -2]`

If I wanted exact distance, Pythagora's theorem comes to mind, but my usecase is a machine learning model, so the simpler the calculation the better. Given this simple example, it seems that it would be enough to sum the coordinates, like so `[ 0+5 (0 + abs(-1)) 2+0 ]`, but will that always preserve the order?

Excuse me being uninitiated.

Comment: What do you mean by "order around the origin"? How do you want to order those points? Maybe you want to know the angle? Also I don't get why you have three points with two coordinates and then you get three with three coordinates. What do those represent?

Comment: I want to order those points by distance, I'll try and update the answer to make that clearer. I'm having trouble with wording, I'll try and use "order by distance".

Comment: Oh well, you just have to order them from the closest to the farthest then? In that case, I don't think you can avoid calculating the distance, because that's what you're looking for. You can calculate the squared distance, so you avoid calculating the square root and you just have $x^2+y^2$ which is elementary to compute.

Comment: But are we talking about the distance from the origin?

Comment: @Harnak, yes, for sake of simplicity. Can you comment on why x+y doesn't work? Also edits to my phrasing are welcome.

Comment: Well, the exact sum doesn't work at all because that's not a distance. You may use $|x|+|y|$ and you're still ordering the points in some way, but it's not through the euclidean distance. So if you want to order the point from the closest to the farthest (in the meaning we give in everyday life), of course, you need to use the euclidean distance. If you want to just order them in some fashion, you may use any distance you want, even $|x|^p+|y|^p$, but that *highly* depdens on what you are trying to do. What is your purpose in this? Give more context.

Comment: The context is, I need to calculate distances to a given point for many points, but the distance has to be precise only insofar that the ordering is correct. In other words, I don't actually need the distance, but the ordering. So I'm wondering if ordering and distance can be decoupled in practice, and can ordering be calculated faster while sacrificing distance precision. I'm implementing Neural Gas.

Comment: Then you have to stick with euclidean distance, if you need to know which is closer in the ordinary meaning. Take for example $(0,1)$ and $(1/2,1/2)$. Using the sum of absolute values you get $1$ for both. Though, their distances from the origin are respectively $1$ and $\sqrt{2}/2$, so the second one is closer. Just use the squared distance, so you don't have to calculate the square root. Computing $x*x+y*y$ will be not a drawback for you computer (if that's what worries you)